# Should I use mainEntity markup for the headline of the generated content?

Tags: seo, schema.org, structured-data, technical-seo, markup

The content of every page on my [website](https://globaltradehelpdesk.org/en) is generated after user input, which in turn modifies the URLs. However, when accessing the website, only a basic landing page is shown. To improve its visibility, I'm designing structured data and gathering relevant markups from schema.org.

One question I have is whether to use the mainEntity markup for the headline of the generated content under the [WebPage](https://schema.org/WebPage) schema.

[image]